# Remove linebreaks before and after text

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following text:

> "\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nSome text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text\r\n \r\nSome other text Some other text Some other text Some other text Some other text Some other text\r\n \r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n".

How can I remove the \r\n before and after the text but keep them in the middle of the text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`String.Trim`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4tt83f9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

> Removes all leading and trailing occurrences of a set of characters specified in an array from the current String object.

```
str = str.Trim('\r','\n');
```

Answer (score 3):

The `String.Trim()` method removes leading and trailing whitespace (including line breaks of any kind). Assuming that you would want to remove leading and trailing tabs and spaces also, you can simply use:

```
text = text.Trim();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Environment.NewLine` as argument to `Trim()` method to remove all the newline characters from the string.

Try This:

```
 string newStr = str.Trim(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray());
```

**EDIT:** `Environment.NewLine` works based on the O.S platform under which you are running the application.

Comment: Nice approach, but this leads to a platform-dependent solution which may not be desired.

Comment: @helb: yes true, but untill unless if OP is working in Windows O.S, it is fine.